# Lightning Open CTI Demo Adapter - Partner Developer Edition

Tags: visualforce, unmanaged-package, opencti

I have installed in a partner dev. edition the Open CTI (This org has namespace) the Open CTI package. I have made the configuration and added in the CTI Adapter URL the link:
https://MYDOMAIN-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/apex/NAMESPACE__demoAdapterPage. However when opening the phone it is displaying a blank page and i get an error in the console:
iframeinterface.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://cgnrulesets-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at Object.handleOnload (https://cgnrulesets-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/support/console/xdomain/30.0/iframeinterface.js:1:357)
at window.onload (https://cgnrulesets-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/support/console/xdomain/30.0/crossDomainProxy.html:4:89)

Any ideas? Is open cti supported in this edition? I have tried lots of things like putting the whole url or just /apex/demoAdapterPage, but haven't found solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing the reference for lightning component in the Visualforce page `demoAdapterPage` from `c:lightningComponentName` to `YOUR_NAMESPACE:lightningComponentName`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        sforce.interaction.cti.notifyInitializationComplete();
        $Lightning.use("YOUR_NAMESPACE:demoAdapterOut", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("YOUR_NAMESPACE:demoAdapter",
            {
            },
            "lightning",
            function(cmp) {
                sforce.opencti.enableClickToDial({
                    callback: function() {
                        console.log('CLICK TO DIAL ENABLED');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```